# Category cant be empty issue in Django rest framework

Tags: django, api, post, django-rest-framework, multipartform-data

I have a product add post API. I am sending all the data that is required but I got the above error every time. I am not sure what is the issue.

**"Category cant be empty"**

But I am sending the data.

```
class Variants(models.Model):
    product_id = models.CharField(max_length=70, default='OAXWRTZ_12C',blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20,default=500)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=SIZE, default='not applicable',blank=True,null=True)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=70, default="not applicable",blank=True,null=True)
    variant_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="products/images", blank=True,null=True)
    thumbnail = ImageSpecField(source='variant_image',
                               processors=[ResizeToFill(100, 50)],
                               format='JPEG',
                               options={'quality': 60})
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=10,blank=True,null=True)  # available quantity of given product
    variant_availability = models.CharField(max_length=70, choices=AVAILABILITY, default='available')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Variants"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_id
#Product Model

class Product(models.Model):
   
    merchant = models.ForeignKey(Seller,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank=False)
    sub_category = models.ForeignKey(Subcategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # is product featured?
    best_seller = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    top_rated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    tags = TaggableManager(blank=True)  # tags mechanism
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150,unique=True)
    main_product_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="products/images", null=True, blank=True)
    thumbnail = ImageSpecField(source='main_product_image',
                               processors=[ResizeToFill(100, 50)],
                               format='JPEG',
                               options={'quality': 60})
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200,blank=True)       
    description = RichTextField(blank=True)
    #picture = models.ImageField(upload_to="products/images", null=True, blank=True)
    picture = models.ManyToManyField(ImageBucket,null=True,blank=True,verbose_name="Add extra 3 images")
    rating = models.IntegerField(choices=((1, 1),
                                               (2, 2),
                                               (3, 3),
                                               (4, 4),
                                               (5, 5))
                                      )
    availability = models.CharField(max_length=70, choices=AVAILABILITY, default='in_stock')
    warranty = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=WARRANTY, default='no_warranty')
    services = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=SERVICES, default='cash_on_delivery')
    variants = models.ManyToManyField(Variants,related_name='products')
```

My view:

```
class ProductAddAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    parser_classes = [MultiPartParser,JSONParser,FormParser]
    # queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AddProductSerializer
```

Here I have used parser class just in case if it works.

Serializer Code:

```
class  AddProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)
    variants = VariantSerializer(many=True)
    slug = serializers.SlugField(read_only=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['id','merchant','featured', 'top_rated','category','brand','collection','sub_category',
                  'name','slug','description', 'main_product_image','best_seller','picture',
                  'rating','availability','warranty','services','variants']
        #depth = 1

    def create(self, validated_data):
         #user = self.context['request'].user

         picture_data = validated_data.get('picture')

         merchant = validated_data.get('merchant')

         category_data = validated_data.get('category')

         featured = validated_data.get('featured')

         top_rated = validated_data.get('top_rated')
         brand = validated_data.get('brand')
         collection = validated_data.get('collection')
         sub_category = validated_data.get('sub_category')
         name = validated_data.get('name')
         description = validated_data.get('description')
         main_product_image = validated_data.get('main_product_image')
         best_seller = validated_data.get('best_seller')
         rating = validated_data.get('rating')
         availability = validated_data.get('availability')
         warranty = validated_data.get('warranty')
         services = validated_data.get('services')
         #variants_logic


     variants_data = validated_data.get('variants')
     #breakpoint()
     print(variants_data)


     # from pudb import set_trace;set_trace()

     #products-logic

     product = Product.objects.create(featured=featured,top_rated=top_rated,
                                      brand=brand,collection=collection,sub_category=sub_category,
                                      name=name,description=description,
                                      main_product_image=main_product_image,
                                      best_seller=best_seller,rating=rating,
                                      availability=availability,warranty=warranty,
                                      services=services,merchant=merchant)
     product.save()


     product.category.set(category_data)             

     # product.variants.set(variants_data)
     product.save()
     for variants_data in variants_data:
         abc = Variants.objects.create(**variants_data)
         product.variants.add(abc)

     product.save()
     return product
```

The data that is sent is this:

```
name: Soap
category[0]: 7
category[1]: 23
brand: 7
collection: 11
availability: in_stock
warranty: no_warranty
service: cash_on_delivery
rating: 3
best_seller: true
top_rated: true
featured: true
main_product_image: (binary)
merchant: 2
variants[0][product_id]: fgfdg
variants[0][price]: 127
variants[0][quantity]: 1
variants[0][color]: red
variants[0][size]: M
variants[0][variant_availability]: not_available
variants[0][variant_image]: (binary)
variants[1][product_id]: fgfdg
variants[1][price]: 127
variants[1][quantity]: 1
variants[1][color]: red
variants[1][size]: M
variants[1][variant_availability]: not_available
variants[1][variant_image]: (binary
```

Comment: Do this   `print(category_data)` and see what will this return ?

Comment: Check if variants is empty, i might be very wrong but just looks like its not accepting the data when its input like category[0] yet looking specifically for 'category'

Comment: @Arjun This data is sent from frontend. I am not sure how this type of form can be sent from postman.

Comment: @Henty yes you are right, but now what to do for this??

Comment: change what you're looking for, either change how the front end is sending it or restructure your backend to handle it. To me it looks like you want your frontend to send the categories as 'category' and 'sub_category' or change your serializer to get('category[0]' and get('category[1]')

Comment: I am using validataed_data.get() method and set it afterwards. Can you write the sample code for me for the serializer and I can try that